# Sql connection using jquery in HTML?

Tags: jquery, html, sqlconnection

Is it possible to get Sql connection using jquery?

If it is possible, please tell me how to get it step-by-step.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery has no helper functions for handling SQL.

It has [Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) functions which can be used to talk to a web service that runs SQL on the server.

Client side JavaScript doesn't have the ability to access [raw sockets](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7408372/19068), so you can't connect directly to a remote database.

There are various client side databases, including [storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Storage), which can be accessed directly with JavaScript (but jQuery doesn't have anything to interact with them).